# How to get probability of each image belonging to a class

Tags: python, classification, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch. I trained and tested a linear classifier (nn.Linear) with an image data set that has 8 categories with the batch_size = 35. 
While testing, I wanted to see what is the probability of the given image belonging to any of these 8 classes. That is why I printed output.data variable. But these numbers are above 1 and they are not summing into 1. (I attached the testing code)
So, my question is what does those numbers mean?

Thanks!

```
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in dataloaders['test']:
        images, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
        outputs = model(images)
        print(outputs.data)

        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        print(predicted)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
print('Accuracy of the network on the 4000 test images: %d %%' % (
100 * correct / total))
```

Comment: Can you post the model class?

Comment: A linear classifier still can (and probably should) contain a Softmax. See e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#Linear_predictor).

Comment: This kind of question suggests maybe you should go back to the basics and understand what you are doing, instead of just using it. Consider this, please.

Comment: So, is the output.data giving me the softmax vector? If it is, why my probabilities can be higher than 1?

Comment: The `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` criterion assumes un-softmaxed network outputs are provided to it. It effectively applies softmax followed by negative log-likelihood loss. The reason it combines them is because softmax alone is numerically not very stable and computing the two operations together can be done in a more stable manner. If you want a valid distribution you should apply softmax to the outputs but shouldn't directly apply softmax to the vector you send to your criterion when training. Also, softmax preserves order so if you're only interested in the argmax then softmax isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get logits as output of your neural network.

Use `torch.nn.Softmax` on output to squash the values into (0,1) range.

BTW. You network should output logits as pytorch's losses (`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` in this case) are designed to work with them while being numerically stable.